# PHPMailer SH: -t command not found - runing script via terminal

Tags: php, cron, phpmailer

I have a problem with a PHP script that sending emails using the PHPMailer library.

When I run the script in Web browser all working well, email is sending, but when I try to run the script via terminal or CRON I got this error: `sh: -t command not found`.

What is a problem?

Comment: Probably your PATH is NOT configured properly.

Comment: Script PATH in terminal? This path is correct, i add in end of scipt echo "test" and in terminal i have
sh: - t command not found
test

Comment: Problem is Send() method  PHPMailer. I comment runing this method, and this script do without error.

Answer (score 1):

This will be because your `sendmail_path` is not set in your php.ini, and this suggests you may also be missing a local mail server for it to talk to. This property is used within PHP to create a command line that incorporates this command, and it appends the `-t` property to it, so if you have no command, you end up with `-t` by itself, which is indeed not a command.

Answer (score 0):

I find Solution, i run script on QNAP and i find a solution on QNAP forum:
https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=60875&p=274526&hilit=sh%3A+t%3A+command+not+found+mail#p274526